# useCallBack executes twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why does the useCallback hook execute twice? I got a warning advising me to use useCallback so I'm trying to do so. From my understanding useCallback will only execute whenever the object we pass to the array is updated. So my goal is for the websocket to connect once a token is loaded. It 'mostly' works; the socket is connected twice, the callback is running twice.

```
const setupSocket = () => {
    if (token && !socket && authenticated) {
      console.log(token, authenticated, socket === null);
      const newSocket = io(ENDPOINT, {
        query: {
          token,
        },
      });
      newSocket.on("disconnect", () => {
        setSocket(null);
        setTimeout(setupSocket, 3000);
      });
      newSocket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("success, connected to socket");
      });
      setSocket(newSocket);
    }
  };

  useCallback(setupSocket(), [token]);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
//Pages
import Home from "./pages/home.jsx";
import LoginContainer from "./pages/login/login.container";
import Signup from "./pages/signup";
import PostDetailContainer from "./pages/post-detail/post-detail.container.js";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
import ProfileContainer from "./pages/profile/profile.container";
import AboutContainer from "./pages/about/about.container";
//Components
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import AuthRoute from "./utils/AuthRoute";
//Redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";
//SocketIO
import io from "socket.io-client";

//Actions
import {
  clearUserData,
  getUserFromToken,
  setAuthentication,
} from "./redux/actions/userActions";

function App({ user: { authenticated }, clearUserData, getUserFromToken }) {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.IdToken);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:3001";

  const setupSocket = () => {
    if (token && !socket && authenticated) {
      const newSocket = io(ENDPOINT, {
        query: {
          token,
        },
      });
      newSocket.on("disconnect", () => {
        setSocket(null);
        setTimeout(setupSocket, 3000);
      });
      newSocket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("success, connected to socket");
      });
      setSocket(newSocket);
    }
  };
  useCallback(setupSocket(), [token]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      //decode token
      const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
      //token is expired
      if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
        //remove token from local storage
        localStorage.removeItem("IdToken");
        setToken(null);
        clearUserData();
      } else {
        if (!authenticated) {
          setAuthentication();
          getUserFromToken(token);
        }
        if (authenticated) return;
        //get user
      }
    }
  }, [token, authenticated, clearUserData, getUserFromToken]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={ProfileContainer} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutContainer} />
            <AuthRoute
              exact
              path="/message/:username"
              component={Message}
              authenticated={authenticated}
            />
            <AuthRoute
              exact
              path="/posts/:postId"
              component={PostDetailContainer}
              authenticated={authenticated}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  clearUserData,
  setAuthentication,
  getUserFromToken,
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: If you are using React.Strict, it will run twice. Check [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074) for details. React.Strict is usually used in index.tsx

Comment: thank you! You should make this an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Okay I have added an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using React.Strict will make your code run twice. Check out [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074) for more information about this.

Comment: If you don't know if you should remove `StrictMode`, [read this](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
useCallback(setupSocket(), [token]);
```

Try this

```
useCallback(setupSocket, [token]);
```

If that was a typo, then I hope you already got the issue. If not and you need explanation, then here it is.

Assume you have a methods like this

```
function foo () {
  console.log('I am foo');
  return 'I am foo'; // Incase 'foo' is not void and returns something
};
```

Way 1: You are executing 'foo' and storing return value in 'refFoo'.

```
var refFoo = foo();
```

Way 2: You are creating reference of 'foo' as "refFoo".

```
var refFoo = foo;
```